# What are signs that metabolism is slowing in dieting?

Tags: diet, metabolism

when you're on a diet and you hit a plateau, they say your metabolism may have slowed because you're in "starvation mode."  My question is, when this happens do you get fatigued/sleep a lot/not have any energy?  Is it obvious your metabolism has slowed, or does your body keep it a secret?

Comment: There's a good reason why diet and nutrition questions are off topic on all SE sites. There just aren't any factual answers. Everything is opinion.